# ¿Como se lleva a cabo el siguiente programa de recursión?

Tags: c

Mi duda viene a que es un poco confuso saber como ocurre la impresión de este resultado: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.

Se supone que si hay una continua recursión hasta llegar a la letra A y finalmente imprimirla. Como se llega a la letra B? Será que la memoria ejecuta todos los printf() comenzando desde A? para luego ejecutar B, después C, etc. en la memoria? Gracias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void funcionA(char c);
void funcionB(char c);

int main()
{
  printf("\n");
  funcionA('Z'); //90
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
void funcionA(char c)
{
  if(c > 'A') //65
    funcionB(c);
  printf("%c", c);
}
void funcionB(char c)
{
  funcionA(--c);
}
```

Comment: Te suguiero que tomes un lapiz y papel y realizes una prueba de escritorio, tbn por cada llamada a cada metodo trata de registrarlo como una pila y te daras cuentas que al final se empieza a ejecutar el `printf`, que en ese momento tiene el valor de `A` y nuevamente se empezara vaciar la pila.

Comment: tbn te aconsejo que agregres un `printf` ha modo de pruebas, en la funcion: `funcionA` al `if` agregale unas llaves `{ ... }` y antes de llamar a `funcionB` realiza un `printf("funcionB('%c')\n", c);` de esta forma podras darte cuenta de lo que esta pasando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La recursión se parece mucho a un bucle: repite una acción hasta que se cumple una condición. La diferencia con la recursión es que vas acumulando llamadas a función y al completar la condición de salida debes *desenroscar* las llamadas realizadas.

Puedes entenderlo mejor simplificando<sup>1</sup> tu código:

```
void funcionA(char c)
{
    if (c > 'A') //65
    {
        funcionA(--c);
        printf("%c", c);
    }  
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n");
    funcionA('Z'); //90
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Cuando llamas a `funcionA`, lo primero que hace es llamar a `funcionA` y lo segundo imprimir el parámetro recibido; dado que lo primero que hace es una llamada a si misma, no llegarás a la segunda instrucción de `funcionA` hasta que *desenrosques* todas las llamadas:

```
FuncionA Z
 funcionA Y
  funcionA X
   funcionA W
    funcionA V
     funcionA U
      funcionA T
       funcionA S
        funcionA R
         funcionA Q
          funcionA P
           funcionA O
            funcionA N
             funcionA M
              funcionA L
               funcionA K
                funcionA J
                 funcionA I
                  funcionA H
                   funcionA G
                    funcionA F
                     funcionA E
                      funcionA D
                       funcionA C
                        funcionA B
                         funcionA A
                         print A
                        print B
                       print C
                      print D
                     print E
                    print F
                   print G
                  print H
                 print I
                print J
               print K
              print L
             print M
            print N
           print O
          print P
         print Q
        print R
       print S
      print T
     print U
    print V
   print W
  print X
 print Y
print Z
```

Puedes comprobar esto dando la vuelta a las instrucciones de `funcionA` y observar que la impresión se hace al revés:

```
void funcionA(char c)
{
    if (c >= 'A')
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        funcionA(c - 1);
    }  
}
```

Muestra:

> ```
> ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
> ```

---

1. La simplificación es para responder la pregunta, el código no se comporta de la misma manera.

Comment: La función que propones no es exactamente la misma que en la pregunta... en la pregunta si llamas a `funcionaA('A')` directamente te imprime el caracter mientras que tu propuesta no imprimirá nada

Comment: @eferion Nota al pie de página.

Comment: Podrías haberte evitado la nota al pie poniendo `c-1`

Comment: Opté por simplificar el código para que el "*diagrama de llamadas*" fuese más sencillo, salía algo mucho más engorroso con el código original... (EDITAR) ah, vale, ya veo lo que dices xD

Comment: perdona por las ediciones, me lié :(

Comment: @eferion todo queda en familia... lo curioso es que juraría haber hecho esas ediciones yo O_o